# JDeveloper hotkeys

Tags: jdeveloper

Does anyone know if theres a shortcut in JDeveloper that do something like the option Find Usages in Netbeans?

Answer (score 3):

In 10.1.3.3, you should be able to right click on a given class and select "Find Usages" (shortcut Ctrl+Alt-U).

The list of usages within the application should appear in the log.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing as user635090 said is applied also to the following versions:

- Jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0
- Jdeveloper 12c

Answer (score 0):

Select the content and use CTRL+ALT+U.

In JDeveloper, go to Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcut Keys for full set of short cut key operations.